# XSLT copy excluding attributes

Tags: xslt, copy

I've got an XSLT that is translating from XML A to XML B and the 2 are 95% the same except for the fact XML B has fewer attributes. So, for example, I need to translate:

```
 <PaymentDetail PaymentType="CC" ItemNbr="6" CcardNbr="9999999999999999" CcardExp="0523" CcardVend="AA" PayRmrk="" Description="Advance Payment" Total="999.99" />
```

to

```
 <PaymentDetail PaymentType="CC" ItemNbr="6" CcardNbr="9999999999999999" CcardExp="0523" CcardVend="AA"  Total="999.99" />
```

I've tried copy with an attribute list, but that seems to be long-winded, the same as just doing element = PaymentDetail, attribute name=..... & basically "hard-coding" the whole thing.

I'm using version 1

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're after. You can either list the attributes you want copied, or the attributes you want to be excluded. Or provide some criteria that will be applied at runtime to make this distinction.

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution uses template rules:

```
    <!-- Default template: copy nodes unchanged -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Drop selected attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@PayRmrk | @Description"/>
```

Comment: You don't. Edited.

Answer (score -1):

You could exclude the attributes you don't need in your Xpath statement :

```
    <xsl:template match="PaymentDetail">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@* except (@PayRmrk, @Description)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

See it working here : http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS26mv

Comment: As the post says "using version 1" I don't think that the XPath 2.0 `except` operator is available.

Comment: I asked myself the question, but then I tried it in xsltfiddle and specified xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" and it worked so I thought it was available.

Comment: The fiddle you have created uses Saxon 9.8 which is an XSLT 3 processor, independent of the version you set. You can switch the processor in the menu http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS26mv/1